# Why won't my success message that's coming from the controller appear in the view?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, bootstrap-4

I'd like to know why my bootstrap success message that's coming from controller (`PostsController.php`) won't appear in the view (`messages.blade.php`)?

I see the Bootsrap success green banner coming about but not the message itself.  What could be the reason why?

Here's `messages.blade.php`:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('session')}}
    </div>
@endif

@if(session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{session('error')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

Here's `PostController.php`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    $post = new Post; 
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post Created');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@if(session('success'))
    ...
        {{session('session')}}
    ...
@endif
```

I think you want `session('success')` inside the div?

Comment: I feel like an idiot.... thank you!  I can't believe I spent 2+ hours on a simple bug, makes me doubt myself sometimes :(.

Comment: We've all been there